# When UICollectionView will fill cells and get height in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a uiCollectionView with some elements. I need to know the collectionView's height before **viewDidAppear** to do some stuff magic. I use the below snippet code:

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
// or
collectionView.contentSize.height
```

However, this is only return true value in **viewDidAppear** and in **viewWillAppear** and **viewDidLoad** others return 0 (before viewDidAppear I need that). I need to know about collectionView's lifecycle and where the elements fill in the collectionView to determine it's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know about height of UICollectionView then use the code

```
collectionView.frame.size.height
```

If you want to know how much scrollable height is then use

```
collectionView.contentSize.height
```

The datasource methods of UICollectionView are called just before the viewDidLayoutSubviews function.

Comment: I use viewDidLayoutSubviews { print height here }. It returns 0 again

Comment: @AmirShabani What did you printed in logs this collectionView.frame.size.height or  collectionView.contentSize.height?

Comment: both of them return 0. Even frame.size.height return zero in viewDidAppear

Comment: @AmirShabani I'm not getting zero is either of the cases I'm getting the value as the height of collectionView. What is you height constraint value in storyboard?

Comment: I add collection programmatically and it's size is "V:[v0]" that the first time is zero.

Comment: @AmirShabani if you have given zero then it will give zero. What you want please give a brief intro. I'll help you with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151782/discussion-between-arun-k-and-amir-shabani).

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView`'s loading is an asynchronous process so you can't be sure the loading is completed before `viewDidAppear` is called.

I suggest you to use KVO to observe value changes of your collectionView's `contentSize`, and perform your magic when the value changes.

Another option "dirty" option from my pov is to do something like

```
collectionView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async{
// This will be called when after reloadData() completes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
 method which returns the size of specified item's cell before rendering it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
     let height = collectionView.frame.size.height
     // Your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you get `contentSize` of `collectionView` before the containing view(ViewController's view) is loaded?. I think you forgot the Life cycle of view.

If your controller contains subViews(like collectionView, tableView). Then first of all main parent `view` is loaded(**viewDidLoad**, **viewWillApper** or **viewDidApper**) and after that all subview is directly loaded in according to view hierarchy.

So you can only get full correctly contextSize after collectionView completely loaded. If you trying to access contentSize before view loaded then it return default value which is 0. So if you want to do some magic animation on collectionView you can hide when initialise, And after complete `collectionView` is loaded then Unhide it and perform animation.